# Find all rings with 2 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How to find all rings (up to isomorphism) with two elements?

Is it only $(\mathbb{Z}_2, +, *)$?

Comment: What are your thought on why that would be the only one? Do you require your rings to have a unit?

Comment: No. But at first, we thought maybe we need an not-abelian group, but we couldn't construct a non commutative ring with two elements.

Comment: @Eknoes  You should edit your question to include your thoughts on the problem rather than making readers search through the comments for them.

Comment: Tbh I think this was treated a bit harshly. The answer below is excellent. But given that the OP (and other readers!) may be unfamiliar with how to manipulate ring things, IMHO it is worth having an answer on record.A ring MUST have a zero (additive identity) element, so we may safely write "0" as one of the elements, and call the other "x" say.  If we take only rings with a (multiplicative) identity "1" then x=1 and that's that. That gives GF(2) as per the OP's example. However if we allow "rngs", then x≠0 could satisfy x+x=0 and x^2=0: eg the matrix (0,1;0,0) over GF(2). That's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: draw the addition and multiplication tables.

There is only one group of 2 elements. That fixes the addition table. Try to prove that the neutral element with respect to addition must be an absorbing element with respect to multiplication: that fixes three quarters of the multiplication table.